# Почему не наследуется так как надо? level дожен быть high а массив должен быть передан в sportTeams, но его нету

Tags: javascript

```js
class School {
  constructor(name, level, numberOfStudents) {
    this._name = name;
    this._level = level;
    this._numberOfStudents = numberOfStudents;
  }

  get name() {
    return this._name
  }

  get level() {
    return this._level
  }

  get numberOfStudents() {
    return this._numberOfStudents
  }

  set numberOfStudents(value) {
    if (value.isNAN()) {
      console.log('Invalid input')
    } else {
      this._numberOfStudents = value;
    }
  }

  quickFacts() {
    console.log(`${this.name} educates ${this.numberOfStudents} at the ${this.level} school level`)
  }
  static pickSubstituteTeacher(substituteTeachers) {
    const randInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * substituteTeachers.length);
    return substituteTeachers[randInt]
  }
}

class High extends School {
  constructor(name, level, numberOfStudents, sportsTeams) {
    super(name, 'high', numberOfStudents);
    this._sportsTeams = sportsTeams;
  }

  get sportsTeams() {
    return this._sportsTeams;
  }
}


const alSmith = new School('Al E. Smith', 415, ['Baseball', 'Basketball', 'Volleyball', 'Track and Field']);

console.log(alSmith)
```

Comment: Вы ведь не создаёте экземпляр `High` и с передачей аргументов путаница.

Comment: Если не ответили на вопрос, может он не верно сформулирован или не понятен? Надо править вопросы,  а не плодить их...